# Including JS file in Vue.js 2 component

Tags: import, webpack, vue.js

I have a JS file from [here](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) that I'd like to include in my single-file component.

I can't include the script tag in my template section, as that results in an error.

I also tried:

```
require('/static/sql.js');
import '/static/sql.js'
```

etc. following the instructions [here](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html).

in the script section of my .vue file, but those either complained that the file couldn't be found, or that the dependency wasn't installed.  It's a large JS file (2 MB) so I'd prefer that it not be compiled by Vuejs/webpack.  If I do an 'import', what function do I import from sql.js?

Should I instead install the node version of the sql.js library, along with its fs dependency?  I would like to serve this as a static webpage, so I don't know if it makes sense to have the 'fs' module in there.

I'm currently just including the script tag in the index.html of my entire app, but would prefer that it just be loaded when I need this specific component.

Comment: There are various questions here... Try to be specific, and provide a [mcve]